error while trying to run bevy fragment shader
I'm trying to achieve a pixelated look to a 3d render in Bevy 0.13.2.
After some tutorial following I've ended up at this for my Bevy side code:
#[derive(Asset, TypePath, AsBindGroup, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct PostProcessingMaterial {
    #[uniform(0)]
    pixel_size: f32,
    #[texture(1)]
    #[sampler(2)]
    source_image: Handle<Image>,
}

impl Material2d for PostProcessingMaterial {
    fn fragment_shader() -> ShaderRef {
        "shaders/pixelisation.wgsl".into()
    }
}

pub fn setup(
    mut commands: Commands,
    mut images: ResMut<Assets<Image>>,
    windows: Query<&Window>,
    mut meshes: ResMut<Assets<Mesh>>,
    mut post_processing_materials: ResMut<Assets<PostProcessingMaterial>>,
) {
    let window = windows.single();
    let image = setup_image(window);
    let image_handle = images.add(image);

    commands.insert_resource(RenderImage(image_handle.clone()));

    let render_camera_bundle = (
        Camera2dBundle {
            transform: Transform::from_xyz(0.0, 0.0, 0.0).looking_to(Vec3::Z, Vec3::Y),
            camera: Camera {
                order: 1,
                ..Default::default()
            },
            ..Default::default()
        },
        RenderCam,
    );

    let render_mesh = MaterialMesh2dBundle {
        mesh: Mesh2dHandle(meshes.add(Mesh::from(Rectangle::new(window.width(), window.height())))),
        material: post_processing_materials.add(PostProcessingMaterial {
            pixel_size: 6.0,
            source_image: image_handle,
        }),
        transform: Transform::from_xyz(0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
        ..default()
    };

    commands
        .spawn(render_camera_bundle)
        .with_children(|parent| {
            parent.spawn(render_mesh);
        });
}

fn setup_image(window: &Window) -> Image {
    let size = Extent3d {
        width: window.width() as u32,
        height: window.height() as u32,
        ..Default::default()
    };

    let mut image = Image {
        texture_descriptor: TextureDescriptor {
            label: None,
            size,
            mip_level_count: 1,
            sample_count: 1,
            dimension: TextureDimension::D2,
            format: TextureFormat::Bgra8UnormSrgb,
            view_formats: &[TextureFormat::Bgra8UnormSrgb],
            usage: TextureUsages::TEXTURE_BINDING
                | TextureUsages::COPY_DST
                | TextureUsages::RENDER_ATTACHMENT,
        },
        ..Default::default()
    };

    image.resize(size);

    image
}

And this is what I've got in wgsl:
struct VertexOutput {
    @location(0) uv: vec2<f32>,
    @builtin(position) position: vec4<f32>,
};

@group(0) @binding(0) var<uniform> pixel_size: f32;
@group(0) @binding(1) var texture0: texture_2d<f32>;
@group(0) @binding(2) var sampler0: sampler;

@fragment
fn fragment(in: VertexOutput) -> @location(0) vec4<f32> {
    // Get the texture coordinates
    let uv: vec2<f32> = in.uv;

    // Modify the UV coordinates to create the pixelation effect
    let pixelatedUV: vec2<f32> = vec2<f32>(
        floor(uv.x * pixel_size) / pixel_size,
        floor(uv.y * pixel_size) / pixel_size
    );

    // Sample the texture using the pixelated UV coordinates
    let color: vec4<f32> = textureSample(texture0, sampler0, pixelatedUV);

    // Output the final color
    return color;
}

The error I am getting is as follows:
wgpu error: Validation Error

Caused by:
    In Device::create_render_pipeline
      note: label = `transparent_mesh2d_pipeline`
    Error matching ShaderStages(FRAGMENT) shader requirements against the pipeline
    Shader global ResourceBinding { group: 0, binding: 1 } is not available in the pipeline layout
    View dimension D2 (is array: false) doesn't match the binding Buffer { ty: Uniform, has_dynamic_offset: false, min_binding_size: Some(12) }

It seems like the group bindings are lining up but maybe I'm not seeing something?

Is it your intention that source_image is to be used for both texture0 and sampler0?

not sure lol, i followed some tutorials from a guy who did it like that.
but i just want to be able to run the shader, if i need to change that i could.
where else would the sampler come from?
edit**
i do want to sample the texture by closest neighbour, not billieaner or anythin
( i want to pixely look)

Can you link the tutorial?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOOOc9-joVo&t=45s&ab_channel=chrisbiscardi
and
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLDMZFR37io&t=628s&ab_channel=chrisbiscardi

i ended up fixing it by changing the group to 2

@NewUser69420 thanks for this, I had the exact same problem with my badly hacked shader after porting from bevy 0.12 to 0.13/0.14 and just increasing the group fixed the problem :)
